# Arrange subset of random shapes in to fixed size rectangle with minimum wastage of space

Tags: geometry

I am trying to build a computer program for following problem.

Problem: I have *n* number of random shapes (sample images are given below) and I have a rectangle. I am looking for an algorithm to arrange random shapes QUICKLY in to the rectangle so that MINIMUM WASTAGE of space occurs. Shapes should not be overlapped but they may be interlocked. It may be possible that NOT all random shapes arranged in the rectangle.

Examples of random shapes [(example-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzKyP.png)[(example-2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByvkE.png)

For example, I have 10 random shapes and wanted to arrange them in 1000 mm x 800 mm rectangle. It is possible that 8 shapes are arranged to get minimum wastage of space.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Area of the shape is known so it's possible to find available space of rectangle.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a very hard problem (in a technical sense) and that there is no QUICK algorithm to solve it.

Comment: This was [also posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39762221/1468366) later on.

Answer (score 1):

If by *minimum wastage* you imply a strong optimality requirement, i.e. not only reasonably low wastage but indeed the least wastage possible, then this is a hard problem even for regular shapes. For example look at [Squares in Squares](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squinsqu/) in [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html). Even for 11 squares in a bigger square, the optimality of the given answer apparently hasn't been proven yet. With more complicated shapes this only gets worse.

If you do *not* require strict optimality, but only looking for some good heuristics, then there is probably a wide spectrum of tradeoffs, starting with a dumb greedy placement which would be fast but wasteful. At the other end of the spectrum you might have code which starts with a randomized placement and then tries to tweak that using some gradient descent to make room for yet another tile. Coupled with genetic algorithms to try out different initial configurations you could get increasingly better results the longer you let this code run. At least in theory.

Comment: Thanks MvG. Yea, by minimum wastage I mean a strong optimality required.